# Optimised Battery Charging Mac

Tags: macos, mac, charging

I've had Optimised Battery Charging disabled on my Mac for the last 6 months. I've now re-enabled it. The feature works by learning your daily charging routine and then it will choose how and when to charge it. I'm wondering whether it has still been gathering this charging data over the last 6 months even though the feature has been disabled. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It won’t matter that you had it off - turn it in and the immediate effects will start and make changes to the charge rate. The big improvement is delaying the fast charge due to temperature while charging (which is immediate) and over a week, it will optimize better based on your wake up schedule, but the algorithm is effective right from the get go for babying the battery charge.

As it builds confidence you don’t need a full charge every morning it will start to avoid charging past 80% at first and then maybe even charge less each night if it’s confident you don’t need lots of energy every day.

Comment: So whether it's enabled or not, it won't change the way it gathers the charging routine data? It makes no difference?

Comment: On another note, I have [a 2019 MBP](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP795?locale=en_US) on charge most of the time because I use it mostly from home. Although the "Optimized battery charging" option is enabled in System Preferences -> Battery -> Battery settings, it nearly always gets charged to 100%. Perhaps that's because my usage, while daily and extended, is quite irregular in terms of when it starts and ends. So I take it off charge requlary once a week and have it uncharged to 15% to 20%. I hope this will prevent the MBP's battery from getting degraded far too quickly!

Comment: The loss of “custom data” is very minor for the change in behavior, @RyderCragie I encourage you to enable it regardless of the past setting or presence / lack of previous usage data